# "Connection Refused" via PHP cURL from GoDaddy Hosting to internally hosted Radarr server's API (jQuery works though?!)

Tags: php, api, curl, shared-hosting

I'm at a complete loss as to why this is failing, so get ready for the novel describing exactly what I'm trying to accomplish and what I've tested so far.

**Goal:**

I'm building a webpage on my GoDaddy hosting account that I want to connect to my locally hosted Radarr server's API via PHP cURL.

I want to use PHP so I can obfuscate the IP, port, and APIKey on the client side. Plus, some of Radarr's API calls I would like to use cannot be run via query string.

**Problem:**

No matter what I try, I am getting nothing but the following error:

`Failed to connect to <MY PUBLIC IP ADDRESS> port <PORT NUMBER>: Connection refused`

*(And yes, this is the publicly opened port, not the internal port on the server.)*

**Setup:**

I installed Radarr on a FreeNAS (11.3-U5) jail hosted in my home. This is working beautifully.

I setup the FreeNAS jail with a dedicated IP address instead of allowing it to NAT internally, just to make sure it doesn't cause any issues.

I configured port forwarding on my router to allow external traffic into the Radarr server. This is working. Note: Xfinity is my ISP, but I purchased the router separately.

I have a GoDaddy hosting account where I've written a webpage to tie into Radarr's API on my local network. Currently, the webpage is also working beautifully to query data from the API, **BUT** it's connecting to Radarr via `$.getJSON` with JavaScript and jQuery.

*(Before anyone says it, yes, I know GoDaddy hosting isn't the best option, but it's the one I'm using.)*

**Testing:**

I swear I've tested EVERYTHING and I don't know why this is failing.

This **IS** working through the JavaScript/jQuery solution, meaning the Radarr server is up and running, the port is properly forwarded through my router, and GoDaddy's hosting isn't blocking the connection.

I **CAN** access the raw JSON API response in the browser simply by entering the full API URL call.

And while I'd say I am versed in PHP, I'm certainly no expert, so I even tried pulling a generic PHP cURL script from another StackOverflow post, changing the URL to mine, and running that with no luck. Note: The original script DID work to connect to another external API though.

Then I tried Postman, which worked, and I used Postman to create a PHP script, but that script failed.

All of the functional testing done on my local network was done using my publicly facing IP address. However, just to be certain, I also tried reaching the API through the browser *off* my network, and that worked just fine.

In a desperate attempt, I also reached out to GoDaddy support to see if they had any ideas. They went as far as creating a test PHP cURL script in the same hosting directory and had it simply pull Google's homepage. That worked just fine.

After GoDaddy was unable to help, I setup a free hosting account and free subdomain on AwardSpace, uploaded the script, and that failed too.

In digging into the Connection Refused error, someone suggested just trying to ping the IP through PHP. I attempted this, but it returned 100% packet loss. Also, I logged into my router and watched the incoming connections as I tested. Using the jQuery solution, I saw the incoming connection and it worked great. Using the PHP solution, it didn't register anything inbound.

Lastly, I have confirmed that the publicly opened port on my router is in the list of blocked port by Xfinity. However, since I can access the server externally through the browser and via the jQuery script, that can't be the issue.

There seem to be many, many, many articles online about the general Connection Refused error, but I haven't found a solution to my problem from any of them.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The IP address you use in your PHP script should be the one provided to you by your ISP. It's not clear if that's what you're using. Do you have a static WAN IP or are you using a dynamic DNS service like [NoIP](https://www.noip.com/) to bind a hostname? To properly test, try using your phone (or its hotspot) so you're connecting from an external network

Comment: I'm sorry that wasn't clear. Yes, I am using the IP provided by my ISP. No, it's not static, but I confirmed it was the same the entire time I was testing. Additionally, I did test using my phone (not connected to wifi) and I also connected my computer to my phone via hotspot for additional testing.

Comment: _someone suggested just trying to ping the IP through PHP_ - ping works through ICMP, not HTTP. Many web devs and server admins block all ICMP responses, so it's not really reliable. But what IS reliable - your web server logs. If a request was established, you should see some debug data.

Comment: _Does anyone have any suggestions?_ - Show the code. You are probably messing with an incomplete url that requires allowed redirects, SSL issues for HTTPS connections, firewall rules, hoster's PHP restrictions that prevent external scrapping, server's misconfiguration for AJAX/non-AJAX/non-browser requests, etc. I also highly recommend you read about `curl_getinfo` for debugging purposes.

Comment: @user1597430 OP said they were able to scrape another external site from their PHP script. My guess would be some sort of restriction at their ISP level preventing requests from the Godaddy origins. Perhaps they could try popping the URL into https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. @user1597430, I realize pint may be blocked, but I'm at the point of trying literally anything and figured it was worth a shot. Also, I've been digging into the logs, but I'm not seeing anything. I still have another place to look though. Additionally, I have tried ```curl_getinfo``` and it hasn't helped me, but you're welcome to view the results: https://pastebin.com/9wWvkpSA  As for your additional suggestions, it' snot using HTTPS, there is no firewall, the hoster of the API is me, and the URL shouldn't require redirects.

Comment: @Phil, I agree I'm probably down to reaching out to the ISP, although I highly doubt they'll be open to helping me as I'm on a residential plan so they won't support hosting servers on it. I did check the downforeveryoneorjustme site, but they won't test with IP addresses, and that's what I'm using.